# Insert lines between based on values in one column but ignores hidden rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have to generate a spreadsheet of upcoming events, and I use a macro that creates a thick line that separates each date from the one above it. It's based on the value change in the "Date" column". However, sometimes I have to filter the data by another criteria (say, the county). In those cases, the offset macro I've been using doesn't always work, as the data that changes and produces the line is in a hidden row, and therefore the line is as well. Can anyone help?

I've tried various ways of defining the range as active cells only, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

The macro I'm using is as follows, without applying to hidden rows:

```
Sub UpcomingLines()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Range("A1:A100" & LastRow)
        If rng <> rng.Offset(1, 0) Then
            Range("A" & rng.Row & ":H" & rng.Row).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've tried integrating SpecialCells like this:

```
Sub UpcomingLines()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Set myrange = Range("A1:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each rng In Range("A1:A100" & LastRow)
        If rng <> rng.Offset(1, 0) Then
            Range("A" & myrange.Row & ":H" & rng.Row).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

However, this generates lines in places I don't want them -- basically, the show up between date changes, but also everyplace there is a hidden row, even if there is no date change before or after the hidden row.

Comment: Seems like however you do this, there could alwys be lines in the "wrong place" when you unfilter your data. Does that matter?  And this  `For Each rng In Range("A1:A100" & LastRow)` should be `For Each rng In Range("A1:A0" & LastRow)`

Comment: No ... I have a macro that will unhide, re-sort and re-draw the data after I've done the filtering I need. And thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub UpcomingLines()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, c As Range, theDate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone 'remove existing borders

    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    theDate = 0
    For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'different date from previous visible row?
        If c.Value <> theDate Then
            'add border to top of row if not the first change
            If theDate <> 0 Then c.Resize(1, 8).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
            theDate = c.Value 'remember this date
        End If
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```